# addEventListener byt tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a file structure like

```
<div id='root'>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</div>
```

Those `<li><li>` tags include some content, and I would like to open/close them, but using a pure javascript only. I've tried so using the `document.querySelectorAll`, for now the code goes something like this

```
let lis = document.querySelectorAll('#root > li');
function show(e) {
  alert('hey');
}
lis[1].addEventListener('click', show(), false);
```

But it alerts only when I refresh the page, not "listening" to the actual click, and I still don't know how to refer a precise element. Maybe there are some articles I could use?

P.S. I can't modify the HTML code, so I can't use `document.getElementById`, and jQuery is also not for me at the moment. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you invoke the show function instead of passing it to the `addEventListener` method.

You should pass the function so that it can be invoked later when the event occurs.

```
lis[1].addEventListener('click', show, false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess I messed up with the listener, now it works!

Answer (score 0):

According to the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Your code is working fine, and there is not an issue of page reload, its triggered instantly

```js
let lis = document.querySelectorAll('#root > li');
function show(e) {
  alert('hey');
} debugger;
lis[1].addEventListener('click', show, false);
```

```html
<p>
  Just for info we are applying listener to lis[1] it means list 2 because array starts with 0 
lis[1].addEventListener('click', show(), false);
</p>

<div id='root'>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 2</li>
    <li>List 3</li>
    <li>List 4</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew about lis[1], typed it just for the example. The problem was in the event listener itself, I called for a function instead of passing the listener name (show() !== show).